# Removing leading Zeros from binary number java

Tags: java, bit

How can i remove leading zeros from binary numbers? For example i want to use 16(decimnal)= 0001 0000(binary) and cut it to 1 0000 -  5bits number. I got loop in another function which works only if there is specific counter of bits. It works if i print for example 4bit number from range 0-16 and get random number(which is between 8-15). I dont want to use any convertion to string.

Range of numbers:

```
List<Integer> integers = IntStream.range(0, number).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Converting to number of bits:

```
((int)(Math.log(integers.get(i)) / Math.log(2) + 1))
```

Comment: What binary numbers are you talking about?  Please post the code that generates them.

Comment: ...or at least tell us the form of the binary numbers...how they're stored.  Are they strings, or is this something you're getting when you print some numeric type?

Comment: I hope that you understand that the entire concept of leading zeros only applies when converting a number to a printed format. The binary form that is stored in memory has just ones and zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the binary numbers are in the form of a string, you can do it like this.

```
String s = "0000000000000000100000000010110";
int i = s.indexOf('1');
if (i >= 0) {
    s = s.substring(i);
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Prints

```
100000000010110
```

To get a binary number of an int with no leading zeros, just do the following.

```
int v = 202;
String s = Integer.toBinaryString(v);
System.out.println(v);
```

Prints

```
11001010
```

Comment: Its List of Integers List<Integer> integers = IntStream.range(0, number).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: That tells me you have a list of integers.  How are you getting the binary values.

Comment: (int)(Math.log(integers.get(i)) / Math.log(2) + 1))

Comment: See my recommendation in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for hint, it solved my problem